# POST via Ajax with Django

Tags: ajax, django, post

Baseado em https://godjango.com/18-basic-ajax/ estou tentando fazer um POST via Ajax usando Django.

Dai eu criei um projeto no GitHub https://github.com/rg3915/front-dj-test

```
#urls.py
    url(r'^customer/add$', 'core.views.customer_add', name='customer_add'),
    url(r'^customer/save$', 'core.views.customer_save', name='customer_save'),
```

## models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

## views.py

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse


def customer_add(request):
    return render(request, 'customer_add.html')


def customer_save(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.POST:
        # return HttpResponse('Salvou')
        data = {'message': "%s added" % request.POST.get('item')}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

## customer_add.html

```
<html>
  <body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <form class="form-horizontal col-sm-4 col-lg-4" method="POST">
    <legend>Cadastrar</legend>
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="id_name">Nome</label>
      <input type="text" id="id_name" name="name" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="id_email">e-mail</label>
      <input type="text" id="id_email" name="email" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
      <button type="submit" id="id_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <script>
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
      console.log($( "form" ).serializeArray());
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/customer/save',
        data: {"item": $("input").val()},
        dataType: 'json',
        encode: true,
        crossDomain: false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
          }
        },
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(){
          // alert('Deu Erro');
          console.log('Deu Erro');
        }
      });
      event.preventDefault();

      // CSRF code
      function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        var i = 0;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
          var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
          for (i; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
              cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        return cookieValue;
      }
      var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

      function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
      }
    });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Mas está dando alguns erros. Veja na image a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber o que precisa ser corrigido para que funcione tudo perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o decorator csrf_exempt na sua função da view, que no caso é *customer_save*

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def customer_save(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.POST:
        # return HttpResponse('Salvou')
        data = {'message': "%s added" % request.POST.get('item')}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: Em `data: {"item": $("input").val()}` ele só está pegando o primeiro campo. Como eu faço para pegar os outros?

Comment: Você pode tentar com: `{ "data": $("#id_do_form").serialize()}`.